# Undefined offset if(in_array)

Tags: php

I have had problems with in_array, I've tried a few options but not avail.
this is my code.

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT PSID FROM kewirausahaan WHERE id_r=:IDR GROUP BY PSID");
$stmt->bindParam(':IDR',$_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($data=$stmt->fetch()){ 
    echo $psid_review[]=$data['PSID'];
    echo'<br/>';
}

$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT PSID FROM jawaban GROUP BY PSID");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($data=$stmt->fetch()){ 
    echo $psid_survei[]=$data['PSID'];
    echo'<br/>';
}

$za=$stmt->rowCount();
$no=1;
for ($z=0;$z<$za;$z++){ 

if(in_array($psid_review[$z],$psid_survei)){ 
    $rev[]=$psid_review[$z];
    $no++;
}
}
```

I am trying to replace **in_array** with **array_key_exists**, but it did not work.
what wrong with my code?

Comment: So `print_r` your arrays and see what's there in them

Comment: Just a question: Aren't you able to *join* the two tables per SQL? So you could get the matching data instantly.

Comment: What exaclty do you want to do?

Comment: ok PBALDAUF, I've tried to join and succeed. Thank you :)